# array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given when use collection as event parameter

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, pusher

Right now I'm using Laravel 8.26 and Pusher 4.1.

**This is my event:**

```
class NotifSeller implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $fields;

    public function __construct($fields)
    {
        $this->fields = $fields->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // return new PrivateChannel('notif-seller.'.$this->fields->seller_id);
        return new PrivateChannel('notif-seller.'.$this->fields->seller_id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        $message = $this->fields;
        return $message;
    }
}
```

**And this is my controller:**

```
        $t = new Transaksi();
        $t->item_id = $request->item_id;
        $t->seller_id = $request->seller_id;
        $t->buyer_id = $request->buyer_id;
        $t->category = 'merchandise';
        $t->amount = $request->amount;
        $t->save();
        
        event(new NotifSeller($t));
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Success');
```

and it will show an error message

`array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given`

Did I have wrong code here? I checked so many tutorial, in their tutorial they can use collection as event parameter, but when I tried it, it turn like this.

Sorry if my English is bad, I'm not an English native and this is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow, so I hope you can understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your edit suggestion @Andrew

Comment: have you tried wrapping $t with array? array($t)

Comment: Yes, i have. I tried wrap it with array($t) and it doesn't work. when i 'dd(array($t))' it converted as array, and i have implemented it on the code. but the error message is same as before.

Comment: Can you show dd(array($t)) result?

Comment: then try to add a empty array $data=[]; before $t and then save everything in $data instead of $t object like $data->item_id = $request->item_id; and so on

Comment: @Psycho it turn into multidimensional array, and i still get error message array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given

Comment: is this right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8UWm.png

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you are using `SerializesModels` Laravel tries to serialize your `public $fields;` prop because it contains a model.

Different potential solutions:

- Try typing the prop `public array $fields;`
- Save the entire model there `public Transaksi $fields;`
- Remove `SerializesModels` trait, technically not needed.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this doesn't solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can **transform** a collection to array by calling (chaining) the **toArray**() method in **Laravel**.

For example:

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200]);

$array = $collection->toArray();
```

Or

```
$array = collect(['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200])->toArray();


/* result

    [
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ]

*/
```